# ios zoomable and cliackable scheme (custom metro app)

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have to make an app with custom scheme (mapkit or google map is not applicable). The scheme is metro of petersburg
[image: svg metro scheme]

Also, there will be beautiful background below this scheme in app. Nodes should be clickable and path animateable. I do know how to make route calculation etc. But I have no clues what technology to use for this map. Maybe spritekit? Please, advice any starting point to lurk. I do not want to use simple clickable scrollview - a lot of tedious work with autolayout these nodes etc. I want clean and modern solution.

Comment: This sort of "what tech should I use to develop my app" question is not a great fit for this site, and you are likely to get down-voted/have your question closed, since questions like this lead to opinion-based answers. (And I'm not familiar enough with SpriteKit to know if it would be a good choice for this. I'd probably develop it myself using Core Animation or UIKit animation.)

Comment: Various ways to approach this, but the requirement of *"path animateable"* will add complexity. Probably the easiest way to make it zoom-able and click-able would be to create it as a vector-based PDF with links and use `PDFView`. To do this with "animate-able paths" you'd probably need to use shape layers.

Answer (score 0):

one of your options is  [bezier path](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uibezierpath).
you can use the [application](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/) for drawing the line and converting the sketch to the BezierPath and touching and the rest of the task is not complex.